# Redirecting C system() output fails only with yq

Tags: c, bash

I'm using yq to convert a YAML document into JSON for use in a C program. In my program, I convert the file to JSON using the command

```
system("yq ea \'[.]\' -o=json .cache/BT_nginx-ingress.yaml > .cache/package.json")
```

However this causes the error:

> Error: write /dev/stdout: permission denied

Thoughout my program, I've used redirection several times with the `system()` command, but it fails in this specific instance.

I can run the command normally from the terminal, without root. I'm using bash on PopOS, so I've also added `bash -c` to the above system() call, but it fails this way too.

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks!

Edit: More details on my configuration. The current working directory is the same as the program's location which is one directory above .cache. The working directory is never changed. I am the owner of .cache and the files inside. The permissions are r/w for me, and the group. I am running the process but not with sudo. `system("echo foo > .cache/package.json")` works!

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details: What user is running the process that uses the `system` function? What is the current working directory? Does the program change the current directory? What are the permissions for `.cache` and `.cache/package.json`? Does `system("echo foo > .cache/package.json")` work?

Comment: @Bodo I've added these details. Hope this gives a better idea of what might be going wrong.

Comment: FYI you don't need to escape single quotes inside a string.

Comment: What happens if you run the same command (`yq ea '[.]' -o=json .cache/BT_nginx-ingress.yaml > .cache/package.json`) manually, from the command line, from the same working directory?

Comment: What if you use `>|` as the redirection operator?

Comment: @JohnBollinger I can run the commands as usual from the terminal. It works from the same working directory. Using the `>|` redirection did not work.

Comment: I don't think we're going to be able to explain this without a [mre].

Comment: Do you use `yq` installed from snap? Have you tried output redirection to different locations and/or using full paths?

Comment: @nsilent22 I was using the snap version before, and redirection worked every time from the terminal but never from the C program. I managed to fix this by adding the yq_linux_amd64 binary to my C program and using that instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to fix this issue by adding the yq_linux_amd64 binary with the C program itself, rather than using the yq package from snap. It works fine now, and can redirect outputs without any issue.